# Quartz Cluster support for Couchbase

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, couchbase

I have to use Quartz Scheduler in a application that uses Couchbase as database, in a clusted scenario.

So I will have more than one instance of the Quartz Scheduler, as depicted here:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

I know that JDBC support for Couchbase is highly experimental so I don't want to use it. Another idea would be to write myself a CouchbaseJobStore class.

Do you know other solutions?

Comment: Any updates on this question? What did you end-up doing? I have the same dilemma and am very curious to learn what you used in the end.

Comment: Any updates @madmaz